# How to display video link coming from API Response

Tags: ios

how to display this type video link from API Resopnse.I want to use webview or `MPMoviePlayerController` to display video link

```
  <iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\"\r\nsrc=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k?autoplay=1\">\r\n</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];
player.view.frame = CGRectMake(184, 200, 400, 300);
[self.view addSubview:player.view];
[player play];
```

May be this helps you.